# Agora io Unity Demo not joining channel

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am using the **Angora Unity SDK 2.9.2.2** and **Unity 2019.4.0f1** on **macOS Catalina 10.15.6**.

I am attempting to get the demo scene to work. I have added an appId, however I am not seeing the onJoinChannelSuccess debug log. It suspect that the **JoinChannel** call is not succeeding.

I have logged out the return from **JoinChannel** and I am getting **-7**. From the documentation I understand that any value below 0 is a failure, but I am not receiving any error messages and the code **-7** is not referenced in the documentation.

Does anyone have any ideas on what this error is, or how I could access more detailed information about it?

Comment: Matt, is there any reason you are not using Unity 2020.2 ?

Comment: You should certainly join the **Agora Unity slack channel** - see you there!

Comment: Actually, there is no good reason why I am not using 2020.2, I will try upgrading the project and seeing if it has any effect.

Comment: Upon further inspection of the documentation, I have found that in other cases, the. error code -7 refers to **ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED**.

Once again, I appear to be initialising the engine, so I am unsure why I would be receiving this error.

Comment: added some more, @mattcarver !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found that my issue was due to the **Agora appId** I was using, which had a certificate activated against it in the agora console, meaning that to successfully connect I had to submit a token at the same time.

To resolve this, I just created a new appId on the Agora site and ensured that it was using the **APP_ID Authentication Method** and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to @Fattie who did everything possible to help and pushed me towards the Slack channel which is really useful and I would recommend for anyone else facing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have this line of code being called,

```
mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = onJoinChannelSuccess;
```

(Note that "onJoinChannelSuccess" could be any function name you choose. The fact that in the demo they made it "the same word" can be confusing.)

Regarding that function, the type is "private async void" (not just "void")

```
private async void onJoinChannelSuccess(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
{
    // "this app" joined Agora
    Debug.Log(">> onJoinChannelSuccess my own uid " + uid);
}
```

--

Further to the comments, you have to

```
public void loadAgoraEngine()
{
    string agoraId = "66666....";
    if (mRtcEngine != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Agora engine exists already!!");
        return;
    }
    mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(agoraId);
    mRtcEngine.SetLogFilter(LOG_FILTER.DEBUG | LOG_FILTER.INFO | LOG_FILTER.WARNING | LOG_FILTER.ERROR | LOG_FILTER.CRITICAL);
    Debug.Log("loadAgoraEngine - seemed OK");
}
```

and then AFTER that you have to

do THREE Things,

```
public void joinAgora(string channelName)
{
    Debug.Log(">> joinAgora .. " + channelName);
    Debug.Log(">> agora version  .. " + IRtcEngine.GetSdkVersion() );

    if (mRtcEngine == null) { return; }
    _setup();

    mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
    mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();

    mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(channelName, null, 0);
}
```

where "setup" is just the callbacks:

```
void _setup()
{
    mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = onJoinChannelSuccess;
    mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined = onUserJoined;
    mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline = onUserOffline;
}
```

any luck?

Comment: That line does indeed exist. I am using the Demo scenes provided with the Agora library, so the set up should be working.

Oddly, in the demo code, the **onJoinChannelSuccess** is not defined as **async**, and unfortunately, even after making the change manually, I am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fattie, I have upgraded to **2020.2.0b** and double checked how the engine is being initialised and it is all in line with your instructions here. Still the same result I'm afraid, although I am now only seeing the **-7** returned occasionally. Now I am mostly seeing **0**, which would indicate success, but the result is still the same and the **OnJoinChannelSuccess** is still not firing.

Comment: it's truly a puzzle, @MattCarver - 10 times out of 10, if you just plain download the demo and run the demo - it works!  You know what, have you go the latest beta of Agora?  It is much better - V3 is awesome

Comment: Generally I hateit when companies use Slack as the support channel, but, the Agora suppoprt on Slack is great.  Simply click around on the Agora web site, and, there is basically a link to join the slack agora-unity channel.  Rick and the guys are super-helpful